# Asymptotic nature of an Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

I am seeking asymptotic approximation of the following integral as $m\to0$ and $m\to1$.
$$\int_{m}^{1} \sqrt{\frac{x^2-m^2}{1-x^2}} dx$$ $(1)$

I substituted $x=mu$ and simplify the integral to

$$m^2\big(\int_{1}^{1/m} \sqrt{u^2-1} du + \frac{m^2}{2}\int_{1}^{1/m} u^2\sqrt{u^2-1} du)$$

Both these integrals can be evaluated  and I get a closed form solution. I was wondering if there is another approach to asymptotically approximate integral $(1)$

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is to change to $x=mu$ which exactly results in

$$m^2 \int_1^{1/m} \frac{\sqrt{u^2-1}}{\sqrt{1-m^2 u^2}} du.$$

You then tried to Taylor expand the reciprocal of the denominator. However, this method is not even self-consistent, much less accurate.

The problem is that the error in the Taylor expansion is comparable to the retained terms near $u=1/m$. You can in principle correct this by splitting the domain and performing *different expansions* on the different parts of the domain.

However, at least the $m \to 0$ case is not as hard as all that, because you don't really need to expand the denominator at all in that case. Indeed, you have $|\sqrt{x^2-m^2}-x|=\left | \frac{m^2}{x+\sqrt{x^2-m^2}} \right | \leq \frac{m^2}{x}$, and so you have $\int_m^1 \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx + O \left ( \int_m^1 \frac{m^2}{x \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx \right )$. That last term is easily seen to be $O(m^2 \ln(m))$ because the singularity in $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is integrable and appears at the other endpoint (so there is no interaction between it and the growth from the $1/x$). So you have $1+O(m^2 \ln(m))$ (discarding corrections that are smaller than the neglected terms).

For $m \to 1$, you have $\sqrt{x^2-m^2}=\sqrt{x-m} \sqrt{x+m}$ and then $\sqrt{x+m}=\sqrt{2m} + O(1-m)$. Meanwhile $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sqrt{1-x} \sqrt{1+x}$ and $\sqrt{1+x}=\sqrt{2}+O(1-m)$. Thus the *relative* error in replacing $\sqrt{x+m}$ with $\sqrt{2m}$ and $\sqrt{1+x}$ with $\sqrt{2}$ is $O(1-m)$. Doing that leaves us to do

$$\sqrt{m} \int_m^1 \frac{\sqrt{x-m}}{\sqrt{1-x}} dx.$$

Any further expansions past this point would start getting subtle, but you can actually just do this integral. After discarding corrections to be consistent with the error term, you get $(1-m) \frac{\pi}{2} + O((1-m)^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. What do you think about my approach?

Comment: @nchom I rewrote the answer using a different method and highlighted why your approach is not valid.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you also include the previous version of the answer? I think it would be a nice reference.

Comment: @nchom My previous version was actually *also* not correct, for a somewhat similar reason to why your idea wasn't correct. The problem was that I wanted to just discard the part on $u \in [b,1/m]$ and match the errors that way, but you can't do that consistently either. You need some approximant on $[b,1/m]$.

Comment: @nchom Having carried this through I see that this method is actually pretty inefficient in general. You may want to look into methods of uniform asymptotic expansion of integrals, in particular the Mellin transform. This helped me with a loosely similar problem that came up in my research.

Comment: @nchom Take a look at this version, it is simpler.

Comment: Thanks. If I modify the integral a bit $\int_{0}^{m} \sqrt{\frac{m^2-x^2}{1-x^2}} dx$, I guess the analysis would be something similar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127529/discussion-between-nchom-and-ian).